# 502 Bad Gateway Nginx Mac OS X Yosemite php56 php-fpm

Tags: mysql, nginx, osx-yosemite, php, php-5.6

I was [Brew’ing PHP, MySQL & Nginx on Mac OS X](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mac/osx-brew-php-mysql-nginx/), but I can't make this work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

phpinfo is working

**/log/nginx/access.log**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2015:21:21:16 -0500] "GET /wp/wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2331.4 Safari/537.36"
```

**/log/virtualhost/error.log**

```
2015/03/14 21:21:16 [error] 82682#0: *59 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /wp/wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/usr/local/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

**/log/php-fpm.log**

```
[14-Mar-2015 21:21:16] WARNING: [pool www] child 6851 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 11147.271614 seconds from start
[14-Mar-2015 21:21:16] NOTICE: [pool www] child 82712 started
```

**My Nginx conf
/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

**My Nginx virtual server conf
/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/local.conf**

```
server {
  listen                *:80;
  server_name           localhost;
  error_log            /log/virtualhost/error.log;
  root                 /server;
  location / {
    try_files  $uri  $uri/  /index.php?$args;
    index index.php;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/usr/local/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

**My php-fpm conf
/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php-fpm.conf**

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
;user = _www
;group = _www
listen = /usr/local/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and solved it by recompiling php with different options:

```
brew uninstall php56 && brew install php56 --with-debug --without-apache
```

Seems to be something that went wrong with the original build, maybe those flags or maybe with the tool chain. I seem to remember it complained about not having xcode cli tools the first time round, then installing them and running the build again. Either way, that worked for me.

SIGSEGV in your FPM log means "segmentation fault", which is something wrong in the err.... guts of PHP I think, not a config thing... Sure someone more intelligent can expand on that ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I had a lot of dead-ends trying to figure this out. After trying BaronVonKaneHoffen's solution, still no beans. I read in the Homebrew documentation after reinstalling:

> OS X 10.8 and newer come with php-fpm pre-installed, to ensure you are using the brew version you need to make sure /usr/local/sbin is before /usr/sbin in your PATH:
>
> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

The `OSX` native `php-fpm` was running, not the one packaged from `homebrew`.

I edited the $PATH file by writing the `.bash_profile` script as follows:

In terminal:

```
cd
touch .bash_profile
nano .bash_profile
```

Then write in the file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:${PATH}
```

and save.

Restart and see if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem, the reason is php process have not write permission for session file path, so the solution is:

1. edit **/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini** and give **session.save_path** a writable directory;
2. **/usr/local/opt/php56/sbin/php56-fpm reload**;